# Hoisting and global variables

Tags: javascript, global-variables, pouchdb

How can I assign the value of the variable "username_show" from this PouchDB document? I have tried the hoisting technique but I think I need to hoist the global variable out of the data structure and then out of the function.

```js
    var db = new PouchDB('myDb');
    var remoteCouch = false;
    var username_show;
    
  function loadSettings(){     
    var settings = {
         _id: "UNa",
         username : ""
    }
  
        
    db.get('UNa').then(function (doc) {
  var username_show=doc.username; 
  
          });
 
  }

  loadSettings();
  alert("The Username="+username_show);
```

Comment: First, you should never use global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your alert runs while `username_show` is undefined because it is being assigned asynchronously in the result of a promise.

In your loadSettings function avoid using the var keyword when referencing your global `username_show` variable.

In order to view the variable after assignment you can call a function in your promise.

```
var db = new PouchDB('myDb');
var remoteCouch = false;
var username_show;

function loadSettings(){        
  var settings = {
    _id: "UNa",
    username : ""
  }


  db.get('UNa').then(function (doc) {
    username_show=doc.username; 
    showUsername();
  });

}

function showUsername() {
  alert("The Username="+username_show);
}

loadSettings();
```